# Exporting function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, import, export

I'm having a problem exporting javascript function because of eventlistener, I couldn't find any solution online, any suggestions?

```
//home.js
let mostDemanded=[1,2,3];
export default function myArr(){
return mostDemanded;}
//removing "Explore" nav nothing special
let moveToMain=document.getElementById("moveToMain");
moveToMain.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    moveToMain.style.display="none";
})

//login.js

import myArr from '../js/home.js';
let arr=myArr();
console.log(arr);
```

//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at home.js:9

Comment: Are you sure there is an element with `moveToMain` id?

Comment: can you be more explicit please ?

Comment: i have html <a href> if you mean it

Comment: Can you give the HTML file?

Comment: sure but where ?